# login to a remote web handler

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2010, internet-explorer, authentication, webclient

I need to login to a remote web handler which is heavily protected, for example the login area is in flash object and I need to do a screenshot of my screen, get the username, password textboxes and submit button coordinates and do mouse clicks and enter values in the code.
While that is working sometimes ok, sometimes not, behind the scene there is a web handler which is doing all the heavy lifting, including post data as a parameter. 
Example will be this one:

```
http://website/GetDataINeed.ashx?F1=REN&O3204=24&O37_CS1_CT5_CG3=18
```

Now, once I'll post that to their server, I am getting back the response body and get what I need exactly.

What I am looking now is if I can somehow login to that web handler via webclient object without all the hassle with screenshots, mouse clicks and button coordinates as it is at this moment, and bypass the login via the flash object in asp page.

Comment: I have edited your title. Please see, "[Should questions include “tags” in their titles?](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/)", where the consensus is "no, they should not".

Answer (score 1):

Have you taken a look at a web debugger like [fiddler](http://www.fiddler2.com/fiddler2/), flash is being run on client side so you should be able to grab the post or get statement and analyze what is being sent